# AWK/SED Split a list if the row starts with OR ends with

Tags: regex, awk, sed, split

trying to split my list by redirecting all the lines that match a condition (starts with OR ends with) into a file otherwise in another one.
Trying to use this AWK but seems not working:

```
awk '{print >out}; /^abc|abc.com$/{out="file2"}' out=file1 MyLargeList.lst
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: `awk '{print >( /^abc|abc.com$/ ? out2 : out1 )}' out1=file1 out2=file2 MyLargeList.lst`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you assign `out` on the first match and then never change it again. In short, you seem to assume that `out=file1` on the command line will be re-evaluated on each iteration of the script, but this is not true.

Also, you print *before* you reassign, so the first match goes to the wrong file.

```sh
awk '{ if (/^abc|abc.com$/) out="file2"
    else out="file1"
    print >out }' MyLargeList.lst
```

As already suggested (without any explanation) in a comment, this can be elegantly but somewhat obscurely rearticulated to use a ternary boolean operator.

```sh
awk '{ print > (/^abc|abc.com$/ ? "file2" : "file1") }' MyLargeList.lst
```

In brief, `x ? y : z` returns `y` if `x` is true, otherwise `z`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '/^abc\|abc\.com$/w file2' -e '//!w file1' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

If a line begins `abc` or ends `abc.com`, write to file2, otherwise write to file1.

Or if you only want to separate the first condition, use:

```
sed '/^abc\|abc\.com$/w file2' file > file1
```

Of course, grep would probably be quicker:

```
grep '^abc\|abc\.com$' file > file2
```

and

```
grep -v '^abc\|abc\.com$' file > file1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this task, in one awk pass, is:

```
awk '/^abc|abc\.com$/{print > "file1"; next} {print > "file2"}' file
```

In general, if you want to print lines to many files, based on many patterns matching, this scales to:

```
awk '/pattern1/{out=f1;next} /pattern2/{out=f2;next} ... {print > out}' file
```

where you probably need a default output (for no matching lines) like this:

```
awk '... /pattern3/{out=f3;next} {out=f} {print > out}' file
```

and in case of many outputs, to avoid the too many open files error, you may need a close statement at the beginning:

```
awk '{close(out)} /pattern1/{out=f1} ... {print > out}' file
```

**Testing**

Here is an example file:

```
> cat file
abc
test
abc.com

test
test
abc
end
```

And the result:

```
> cat file1
abc
abc.com
abc
> cat file2
test

test
test
end
```